# these organizations or those organizations?

Tags: determiners, demonstrative

Consider a hypothetical quote:

> Each day we gather information from manufacturers, distributors,
>   Russian and foreign vendors, research centers. The reliability of the
>   sources is ensured by our contacts with employees in **those**
>   organizations.

**Those** is [used to describe](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19772/whats-the-difference-between-these-and-those) objects that are more distant, either physically or in the abstract sense. But could we say "**these** organizations" here, since they have been introduced in the first sentence and hence made somewhat "closer" to the reader? Or would that be a mistake?

Comment: Both of *these* and *those*, as the plurals of *this* and *that*, can be used for referring back. See also http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13993/3281.

Comment: On a side note, you have used both American and British spelling in your question: "organization" is American and "organisation" is British. It is advisable to stick to the accepted set for your location (not necessarily important for this site, of course, but in other contexts it might matter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Those is used to describe objects that are more distant, either physically or in the abstract sense.

This says it all! Here, *distant* does not refer to the placement of those words in the sentence. This answers your concern with *first sentence mentioning.* Others may answer various aspects.

Check this -

> I have many relatives in New York, Sydney, and Tokyo. Those all (relatives) have their own cars.

Comment: That's wassup, Mauilik! Now I've become curious regarding the use of "that says it all!" instead of "this says it all!". Demonstrative determiners are interesting.

Comment: I think *I have many relatives in New York, Sydney, and Tokyo. They all have their own cars,* might sound less awkward.

Comment: @DamkerngT. *Not only in Egypt, there are pyramids in X, Y and Z countries as well. Those all are worth visiting.* :) Ah, *countries* again! Well, I'm talking about the countries in continents!