# What Neo has not figured out

Tags: sentence-meaning

The following dialogs are selected from **The Matrix Reloaded**:

> Neo: D'you already know if I'm going to take it?
>
> The Oracle: Wouldn't be much of an Oracle if I didn't.
>
> Neo: But if you already know, how can I make a choice?
>
> The Oracle: Because you didn't come here to make the choice, you've already made it. You're here to try to understand why you made it. I thought **you'd have figured that out** by now.

and

> Neo: What do you want, Smith?
>
> Smith: Oh **you haven't figured that out?** Still using all the muscles except the one that matters. I want exactly what you want. I want everything.

I still have not figured out what Neo has not figured out.

Help me clarify what Neo didn't understand at that time.

Comment: *That* is used to refer back to things that have just mentioned. In the first scene, "that" refers to "You're here to try to understand why you made it (the choice)." In the second scene, "that" refers to "what Smith wants". See also: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13993/3281.

Comment: I think this is ambiguous. The "that" in the first scene could mean *I thought you'd have figured out that you're here to try to understand why you made that choice by now* or it could mean *I thought you'd have figured out why you made that choice by now.*

Comment: Neo is one person, it should be "I have not figured out what Neo has not figured out." "You have ..." because you comes from the plural when English had thou for the singular, people started using you for one person to be polite.

Comment: It's gotta be the former! If Neo had figured out why he made that choice before his meeting with The Oracle, she would have seen beyond Neo's final choice in the TV room. @ starsplusplus

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. @QuentinUK

Comment: No, the answer is this: he has to understand that he is the one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, in the first case, all you need to do is read the sentences in reverse order:

> Because you didn't come here to make the choice, you've already made it. You're here to try to understand why you made it. I thought you'd have figured that out by now.

= I thought you'd have figured out that + you're here to try to understand why you made + the choice that you already made.

---

In the second case, again - just read in reverse order:

> Neo: What do you want, Smith?
>
> Smith: Oh you haven't figured that out?

= Smith: Oh, you haven't figured out what I want?

(that being said, it's been years since I've watched the Matrix, so I don't remember the context at all)

Answer (score 0):

First, the definition of the phrase in concern!

> [figure out](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/figure-sth-sb-out) - *to finally understand something or someone, or find the solution to a problem after a lot of thought*

Scene 1:

The Oracle wonders that Neo **does not know** why is he there! She clarifies her wondering by saying, "I thought you would have figured that out."

Neo thought that he's there to *make a choice* but he already had made the choice and he was there to know *why he did that*.

Scene 2:

This time, Smith is surprised that Neo still does not know that he (Smith) wants everything!

Comment: Smith also says he wants exactly what Neo wants, but I don't think Neo wants everything. This confuses me!

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng that's teasing him. Neo does not want everything but probably Smith thinks that he's the **one** and for **the one**, everything is his.