# Difference between These & Those

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, grammaticality, word-meaning

I would like to know what is the exact difference between These & Those.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! I have edited your question a bit because we try to keep as much to the point as possible here ( no greetings, thanks or other stuff not related to the question). What you _should_ do, though, is to give examples and show your own prior  research. What did your dictionary say? Do you have example sentences? This makes your question much better! You can always edit your own question by clicking the "edit" button underneath and I suggest you do so.

Comment: You should be able to determine this easily by looking up the words in a dictionary. If you still don't understand, please edit your question and say which definitions you found and why you're still confused.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName I believe that simple words such as these (*these* and *those*), though easy to find in dictionaries, aren't easy to cope with by just using dictionaries. On the other hand, I agree that it'd be better if the OP included some specific examples.

Comment: For the OP, *these/those* are the plurals of *this/that*. You can use them to refer to things that are near/far. You can also use them for referring back-or-forward/back. You can read about the usage of referring back/forward of *this/that* (which is also applied to  *these/those*) here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13993/3281.

Comment: @DamkerngT. - I wish I could upvote that first comment of yours ten times, but, alas, I can only upvote it once. I just looked up _these_ and _those_ in Collins, and, if there was ever two words that would be hard to figure out by reading the dictionary, these (those?) would be two of them. Haidy, this is a good question, perhaps you could read [this meta post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439), along with [this answer](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please/465#465), to get ideas on how to add some information that would get it reopened.

Answer (score 2):

I think this picture explains it better than any words I could write.

[image: this/that/these/those apples]

Comment: What's the source for this image? I'm assuming you didn't make it...

Comment: It is a Vietnamese site http://tienganhthayhoc.com/bvct/chi-tiet/262/this-that-these-those.html

Comment: I just used google images, and found this near the top.

Comment: Those are good pictures, but they don't tell the entire story. Read about my adventures in the [donut shop](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2838/difference-between-this-and-that/2839?s=1|0.0292#2839) for more information.